# joomla - How to show search query in link on addressbar

Tags: php, jquery, search, joomla, filter

My question is:

How can I make my search/filter/ordering fields can be shown in the link after the search button is clicked. I have my model-controller-view-layout files. In model file requred fields are set as state variable in populateState function and are retrieved by the buildWhereQuery function to make it useable in querystring. Everything is going correct up to this point. But from now my problem arrises as what if a user want to send the listing link to his/her frind to show same listing. I need to set the link for this porpose but I don't know how to do this.

I just wrote a function for this in view file as following but I couldn^t figure out how can I use this created link to work. (the variable query is $query = $this->get('state'); in the format of JObject.

```
protected function preQuery($query){
    $params = array();
    foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
        if(!isset($query->$key) || empty($value) || $value == ''){
            unset($query->$key);
        }else{
            if(strpos($key,'filter') || in_array($key, array('limit','limitstart','order','order_Dir'))){
                $params[$key] = $value;
            }else{
                unset($query->$key);
            }                    
        }
    }
    $que = JURI::buildQuery($params);
    $cur = JURI::current();
    return (strpos($cur,'?') ? ($cur.'&'. $que) : ($cur.'?'.$que));
}
```

**EDIT:**

Layout file contains the form which contains the all inputs some for redirection like view task layout component as joomla requred. Some for filterineg or searching. So I couldn't use the GET method for form :/

Answer (score 0):

The search is starting from a form. Now you have two cases.

If you are invoking your view directly from the form, simply change the form method to GET (instead of the default POST) so your form will look like

```
<form method="GET" ....
```

If you however are invoking a controller, and in turn the controller redirects to the form, you might need to change some logic.  In this latter case, it doesn't matter if you use POST or GET invoking the controller; but the controller must not set the user state variables, instead add the parameters to the URL you are redirecting to

```
setRedirect(JRoute::_("index.php?option=com_something&view=results&param1=SOMETHING etc.
```

A final alternative after your comment: to only include some fields in the URL, assuming you are pointing directly to the view:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo JRoute::_("index.php?option=com_yourcomponent&view=yourview&explicit_param_1=something&explicit_param_2=somethingelse
<input type="hidden" ...
```

but this poses more problems as the page should be able to function both with and without the extra params, which won't be present if the user shares the url.  You might be better off handling this in a (sub)controller without a redirect (just instantiate the view and its display method in the controller function being invoked).

Remember you can have the syntax task=subcontroller.task to shorten your url.

Comment: I am using master controller and the subcontrollers releated with views. I am using the sub-controllers for views specific tasks. So the form redirects directly the page but there are some hidden and unnecessary fields to not be sent. Does this function works in sub-controller display method?

Comment: You could use a mix: let the form method be POST, but insert the parameters in its action (I updated my answer) but it's fairly complicated

Comment: I think I will use js when the page loaded function will generate the url like index.php?option_component.JURI::buildQuery($params).'&Itemid='.$itemid and a js variable will keep this and manipulate the address bar link.